# Firebase Cloud Messaging Programatically with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I might be a little slow here, but is is possible to send push notifications with firebase programatically?

Let's say I have an iOS app and a button event. When I press that button I want to send a push notification to certain users via firebase that says 'Hello World!'.

The only way I see now to accomplish that is to use the notification console, but I want to do it programatically. Do I actually have to have my own server to do this?

What do you recommend as the easiest way nowadays to send remote push notifications programatically besides having my own server?

Comment: This is a super vague question as without knowing why, we may provide the wrong answer. Yes you can send notifications programmatically but in many cases that's the wrong solution - you would want to use Observe and Query's to notify clients of events for example.

Comment: Ok, if it is the wrong solution. What is the correct solution?

Comment: Again, without understanding the use case, there's no way to make a suggestion one way or the other. I understand your Hello, World but that's not what you are ultimately trying to do. Why do you want to send push notifications, what will they contain? Why aren't you using Observe and Queries so clients know about changes to the data? Have you gone through the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) guide which covers how to notify clients without push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no. There's no recommended way of doing this through Firebase Cloud Messaging without having your own server to perform the logic. (I wouldn't make calls to the service from the client like Dupinder recommended, as it will leak your server key to the world, which is a Bad Thing Indeed)

That said, it's certainly a feature request the team hears about quite frequently so it's something they're certainly aware about and looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure do NOT include the server-key into your client. There are ways "for not so great people" to find it and do stuff... The Proper way to achieve that is for your client to instruct your app-server to send the notification.

You have to send a HTTP-Post to the Google-API-Endpoint.

You need the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key={your_server_key}
```

You can obtain your server key within in the Firebase-Project.

```
HTTP-Post-Content: Sample

{ 
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification Title",
        "text": "The Text of the notification."
    },
    "project_id": "<your firebase-project-id",
    "to":"the specific client-device-id"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can send push notification with firebase programatically.I have try this by getting the device token of both the users and hitting one api at the send button .Just have a look..

```
let url  = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

request.setValue("your server key ", forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization") // your legacy server key


  request.setValue("ebl0RxL94Ss:APA91bGXn_i6TLcXC1rZZSO1pKXCnqKjg-SxOHsjdahoJ4qIjVxX6dwal3YNeCvpHltEnwHibEuldWzfTiQewgD_J_4HIg31VE_vyvONdHN9v6VQGRcY6PaXY1xZmJ9t_cKfs7sQ9K1q", forHTTPHeaderField:"Authentification") //  sender refreshedToken 


 request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

  request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

 let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

 // dictionary containing sender refreshedToken and  other notification detail including text

let json = ["to":"c6HixiMte3A:APA91bFfNvQev2qcZqdsnJ9qoho_GlXRj1PWx6FWleScgExBi95WAkRqmp2jilCbZYoifs9bfHPyGpofjTAM239SYEiAwMRzgAONFv_KH-u49pG9C6f6UEVY4WEctjFzek9WZ7pBv31t",
               "priority":"high",
               "content_available":true,
               "notification":["body":"new messages","title":text,"score":"5x1","time": "15:10"]]


        do {

            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

           request.HTTPBody = jsonData 

           } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

        // insert json data to the request

 let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())


 let dataTask = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 

            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")
            print(response,data)
            print(error)
        }

        dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Don't do this! By doing so, you've essentially leaked your server key to the client and Bad People could start using it to spam your users with  notifications that would look like they're coming from your app.

Comment: @Dupinder. I am confused. Are you using the server key on the client side in this code? That is dangerous.